# Is there any property that captures $F(\alpha x) \geq \beta F(x)$ for $1>\alpha,\beta>0?$

Tags: probability-distributions

Given a CDF $F:\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}\to [0,1]$ such that $F(\alpha x) \geq \beta F(x)$ for some $1>\alpha,\beta>0.$ I'm trying to figure out if there is any known family of distributions for which this condition holds. Is this somehow related to log-concavity? Is there any connection to reverse hazard rate?

Comment: Trivial example: $X\sim\operatorname{Uniform}(0,a)$ with $a>0$. Then $F_X(x)=x$. It follows for $\alpha>1$ and $\beta>0$ that $F_X(\alpha x)\geq \beta F_X(x)$ whenever $\alpha\geq\beta$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm actually looking for something more general than examples, rather a known condition (like log-concavity, regularity, MHR etc.) or at least the connection to such families

Comment: @Aaron Hendrickson You forgot what happens for $x>a$. @ Tal Alon If $\alpha > 1 \ge \beta > 0$, the inequality holds for all distribution function on $\mathbb{R}_+$, but it is not very interesting. If $\beta>1$, it cannot hold for all $x \ge 0$, because of the limit of $F$ at $+\infty$ is $1$.